# Two simultaneous AJAX requests to same action causing error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-await

I have the following action:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Cart(bool refresh = false, bool mobile = false)
{

   var user = await Auth.GetUserAsync();
   //rest of the code

}
```

Which is being called twice by 2 AJAX calls at the same time (one to render mobile partial, other normal page).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("basket").html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>');
   $('basket').load(PartialURL + "/Cart");
   $('MobileBasket').load(PartialURL + "/Cart?mobile=true");
});
```

The real problem occurs in `Auth.GetUserAsync()` function.

*Code:*

```
  public static async Task<User> GetUserAsync()
    {
        
            if (HttpContext.Current == null || HttpContext.Current.Request == null
                || HttpContext.Current.User == null || HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated == false)
                return null;


            //if session does not exist, but user is logged in, fill session information
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session[sessionKey] == null && HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated)
                using (var dal = new DAL.DAL())
                {
                    //load user from DB
                    var user = await dal.SingleOrDefaultAsync<User>(m => m.Email == HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
                    HttpContext.Current.Session[sessionKey] = user;
                }


            return HttpContext.Current.Session[sessionKey] as User;


    }
```

In one of those calls, the function returns user normally, but the other call produces following error (screenshot from fiddler). Notice how the first call was successful.

[image: Error - fiddler]

Code for `SingleOrDefaultAsync` is following:

```
 public  Task<T> SingleOrDefaultAsync<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) where T : class
    {
        return  _context.Set<T>().SingleOrDefaultAsync(predicate);
    }
```

I have checked while debugging, and email is present in both of the requests, _context is not null, and the user with requested email exists, but one of those always returns an error. Error is returned randomly. Sometimes in first, sometimes in second AJAX call.

Can someone please tell me what is causing this error? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you take one of the calls out do you ever get errors on the single call?

Comment: @JMJ no, i do not. I just get it when there are 2 calls.

Comment: What is difference in the content between the two versions? With you have a mobile version, surely it's better to either do mobile detection in the controller for a single call, or just use the same content but not render all of it for mobile?

I really think that a better solution is required, rather than trying to fix this one.

Comment: @JMJ it is a responsive HTML template, and it has 2 carts (for wide and narrow displays - as you resize window).
I understand that this could be done in one call, but what is the cause of this error? Why does it work in one, but not another call.

Comment: Race condition from the same resource from the looks of it. Responsive design should mean one call and then you can do the rest with CSS and JS. If you're doing a call for mobile and desktop/other, then it's not truly responsive.

FWIW, the true responsive will probably cause you a lot less problems and will give a lot better UX.

Comment: @JMJ i understand your remarks, but I do not see how does it explain why this error is happening. In the future it could be related to a different scenario, and i would still have to find a solution for it.

Comment: In here you are using a static method. in that case you are using the same instance and not two different instances eventhough you have used two different calls. May be your first call is setting "HttpContext.Current.Session[sessionKey]" to null, which will be caught by the second call.

Comment: @Robert I'm saying that they look like they share some kind of resource somewhere along the line. Only one can can use that resource at a time, so one of the requests will always fail - the one that doesn't get to the resource first. (Possibly session related, or the DB)

I don't have your exact codebase in order to debug (not that I can do that right now) so I can't give you a 100%. What I am saying though, is that need dwell on this issue as it's not a good implementation anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would assume, because of the other checks you have in place, that `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` (or even `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity`) is null, and that that's what's causing the error.

This might be so if the first request has caused the authentication process to *start*, but that process is not yet complete - so that the null checks you have succeed, but the subsequent member access fails. In other words, you have a timing issue / race condition. That's just a guess, though.

**Update**: following my suggestion to store the name in a variable and use the variable in the lambda, everything worked. But why?

My theory is that the expression passed to your `SingleOrDefaultAsync` method included the *expression* `HttpContext.User.Identity.Name`, rather than the *value* of that expression.

This expression was then evaluated in your DAL, where `HttpContext.Current` was (presumably) `null` (assuming your DAL is not in your web project). QED?

Comment: I have checked both requests, and `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` was present in both.

Comment: Can you try creating a variable `var name = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name` and using that in your lambda? And let's stick in a null-check for it while we're at it...

Comment: it seems that this worked. When i store name to a variable, i do not get that error anymore.
I also added a null check, but it never went in. 
What is a reason for this behavior?

Comment: you saved the day. Thanks !